# Saving Pixastic Images

Tags: javascript, pixastic

I have been playing around with todataurl following some advice but to no avail.

I am using the pixastic processing library and the manipulated image is placed in a div. I want a way to be able to temporarily store these images so that they can be stored on the server for later use on the same page.

Any suggestions?

Here is a [Demo Page](http://danielrhyshardy.com/http://danielrhyshardy.com/Image/imageedit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d').canvas.toDataURL()
```

to get PNG image base64 decoded.

After it you can save image to server or in html5 localStorage.